# "Compactly closed" subsets of a weak Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

A subspace $A$ of $X$ is  $\underline{\text{compactly closed}}$  if for any compact Hausdorff space $K$ and any continuous map $g: K \to X$, the pre-image $g^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $K$.

A topological space $X$ is $\underline{\text{weak Hausdorff}}$ if for any compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous map $g:K \to X$, the image $g(K)$ is closed in $X$.

In Chapter 5 of May's algebraic topology, he mentioned that when $X$ is weak Hausdorff, $A\subset X$ is compactly closed implies that the intersection of $A$ with each compact subset of $X$ is closed.

I can see that  $A\cap g(K)$ is closed in $X$, but I don't know how to generalize this to all compact subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K \subseteq X$ is compact (which May uses to mean compact Hausdorff, as mentioned at the start of that paragraph (!))  then $i: K \to X$ (the embedding) is a continuous map from a compact space into $X$ so by weak Hausdorffness of $X$ we know that $i[K]=K$ is actually closed in $X$. And now, if $A$ is compactly closed, $i^{-1}[A]= A \cap K$ must be closed in $K$ and hence closed in $X$ too (closed in closed is closed).

Comment: @EricWofsey True, I mentioned that parenthetically.

Comment: Haha, I forgot that $K$ is actually Hausdorff!

Comment: @co-co-nuts Yes, that's important here. Glad I could point you in the right direction and it goes to show: "always read all the definitions an author uses"...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma indeed.